# How "While" and "With" differ from each other?

Tags: prepositions, conjunctions

> 1. Part A should be attached to part B **while** part C remains attached to part D.
> 2. Part A should be attached to part B **with** part C (being) attached to part D.

I know "with" has a usage similar to that of "while", but unsure how they differ.  For the above two sentences I created, I would like to know which is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Sentence 2 is not correct unless you remove the parentheses around 'being.'

With that said, `Part A should be attached to part B, while part C remains attached to part D` and `Part A should be attached to part B, with part C being attached to part D` mean the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Q.
**Part A should be attached to part B while part C remains attached to part D.**

**Part A should be attached to part B with part C (being) attached to part D.**

I know "with" has a usage similar to that of "while", but unsure how they differ. For the above two sentences I created, I would like to know which is correct.

---

Both are correct and you do not need to include (being)

Although both sentences have a different meaning

**Part A should be attached to part B while part C remains attached to part D**

means *A & B need to be put together (assembled) but C & D are already assembled*

**Part A should be attached to part B with part C (being) attached to part D.**

means *A & B need to be put together and C & D need to be put together if not already assembled*